# Foundry scripts run with an unknown tx.origin address. How do I change it?

Tags: contract-deployment, foundry, cast

I am running a foundry script that deploys some contracts and calls them.  I start my run function with

```
      function run() public {
            uint256 deployerPrivateKey = vm.envUint("PRIVATE_KEY");
            vm.startBroadcast(deployerPrivateKey);
...

            address(contract).call(
                    abi.encodeWithSignature(
                        "function(uint256,bytes8,address)",
                        var1,
                        var2,
                        var3
                    )
                );
                vm.stopBroadcast();
            }
```

Inside of the contract being called, I always get tx.origin as the address: 0x1804c8ab1f12e6bbf3894d4083f33e07309d1f38.  I am assuming this is some kind of foundry script deployment address.  The msg.sender is the correct address of mine, however.

I am able to set both the tx.origin and msg.sender properly if I use vm.prank(), but I need the script to interact with an existing contract on-chain.  I think I need startBroadcast for that instead of vm.prank().

Is that address indeed a default deployer address?

How can I get the tx.origin to be my address instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While executing the forge script command, include `--sender` or `--private-key` wallet options to change the `tx.origin` address.

Comment: Where did you see that in the docs?  Exactly the issue I was having.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Answering to Yan's question in the comments.

There's only two references to this address 0x1804c8AB1F12E6bbf3894d4083f33e07309d1f38 in the Foundry docs.

You can check them out here:

https://book.getfoundry.sh/reference/config/testing

It's the default address for `msg.sender` and `tx.origin`.

```
sender
Type: string (address)
Default: 0x1804c8AB1F12E6bbf3894d4083f33e07309d1f38
Environment: FOUNDRY_SENDER or DAPP_SENDER
The value of msg.sender in tests.

tx_origin
Type: string (address)
Default: 0x1804c8AB1F12E6bbf3894d4083f33e07309d1f38
Environment: FOUNDRY_TX_ORIGIN or DAPP_TX_ORIGIN
The value of tx.origin in tests.
```

There're no other references to this address anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

I was also struggling with same problem. I discovered that you can override `tx.origin` address in `foundry.toml` file. I don't know why this is not working with `vm.prank()` or `vm.startPrank()`.

**I override both these variables to assign desired address to `tx.origin` in tests.**

```
[profile.default]
src = "src"
out = "out"
libs = ["lib"]
// added lines
sender = '0x9dF0C6b0066D5317aA5b38B36850548DaCCa6B4e'
tx_origin = '0x9dF0C6b0066D5317aA5b38B36850548DaCCa6B4e'
```

There is full default foundry.toml file with default values:

https://github.com/foundry-rs/foundry/blob/master/crates/config/README.md#all-options